# check if id not exist in join table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables. Table I and Table II contains the message contains the username id and the id of messages. I did every user after seeing the messages recorded in Table II. If a user has not read a message I want to notification. What is the quickest and most efficient way?

```
tbl_msg
id    title   msg  user_id ucid all
1     msg1    text  *        *
2     msg2    text

tbl_msg_log
id  user_id   msg_id
1     2         2
2     1         2
```

i know using foreach is too old . so how can i join two table and check if user_id and msg_id not exist in table msg log?

Update 1

i used this sql but not work :

```
$get_msg_notifiction = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_msg` WHERE (`user_id`='$user[id]' OR `ucid`='$user[group_id]' OR `all`='1') AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM tbl_msg_log WHERE tbl_msg.id = tbl_msg_log.msg_id AND tbl_msg_log.user_id = $user[id])");
```

return :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute()
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Did you get an error message? If so, which? Or were too many rows returned or too few or wrong ones? Your query checks columns tbl_msg.user_id, tbl_msg.ucid and tbl_msg.all, but above you say tbl_msg contains only the three columns id, title, and msg. So: Which is correct?

Comment: tnaks question update ...

Comment: The query looks fine to me, but I may be wrong of course. You should tag your request with PHP, so PHP guys can help you get to the actual error.

Comment: thanks . i use your suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Use NOT EXISTS:

```
select * from tbl_msg
where not exists (select 1 from tbl_msg_log
                  where tbl_msg.id = tbl_msg_log.msg_id)
```

If you really must do a join:

```
select tbl_msg.*
from tbl_msg left join tbl_msg_log
                  on tbl_msg.id = tbl_msg_log.msg_id
where tbl_msg_log.msg_id is null
```

Comment: thanks @jarlh can i use this : select * from tbl_msg
where user_id =? And group_id=? AND not exists (.....

Comment: @user3243573, I suppose you can. Try and see what happens!

Comment: @user3243573 The `user_id=` should be placed within the `not exists` subquery.

Comment: thanks @jarlh but i dont underestand , can u correct my query and insert to answer ?

Comment: @user3243573, which table do these new columns belong to?

Comment: table 1 and table 2 have user_id . user_id form table 1 show if msg is only for this user and ucid show if msg for gorup of users and if all ==1 show msg is for all users ... @jarlh

Comment: @user3243573, try and adjust your sub-select's where to "WHERE tbl_msg.id = tbl_msg_log.msg_id AND tbl_msg_log.user_id = tbl_msg.user_id"

Comment: is not correct maybe in table_msg message belong to group of users . and with these method notifiction is empty @jarlh

Answer (score 0):

This lists the messages which have not been read

```
SELECT tbl_msg.*
FROM tbl_msg_log 
LEFT JOIN tbl_msg 
     ON tbl_msg_log.msg_id=tbl_msg.id
WHERE tbl_msg.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Will message id 1 be returned?

Comment: Yes , row of table tbl_msg with id 1